# dimple - make line dotted for only part of the chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, linechart, dimple.js

Using dimple, how can I make the right-most data point in a line chart be connected to the previous data point by a *dotted* line, while the rest of the line chart still uses a *solid* line?

(Think a chart with a future projection at the end, or any situation where the final data point is "different" than the rest.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know dimple.js. The approach used in an Excel chart would be to plot a second data series and let the "connecting" data points overlap.

A similar approach should be possible with any tool that produces line charts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest splitting your data to "real" data and "expectations"/"forecast" data, and create a series for each one.

The real data would contain all data points except for the right most one.
Forecast-data will contain only the two right most points.

For the real data draw the chart as usual and for the forecast data create a line chart with custom classes as shown here: [Custom Classes](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_bars_sketchy)

The line class should look like:

```
.dotted-line {
    stroke-dasharray:"10,10";
}
```

and before drawing insert the custom class as the class for axisLine:

```
 myChart.customClassList = {
      axisLine: 'dotted-line'
}
```

More on customClasses can be found [here](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#customClassList)

More on dotted lines can found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_stroking.asp)